# What is required to get onActivityResult to fire from a camera selection?

Tags: android, camera

I have the following code which creates an intent to either choose a photo from a gallery of the camera:

```
public void onPhotoButtonClick(View view) {
    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "photos" + File.separator);

    root.mkdirs();

    String fileName = String.format("photo_%s.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());

    File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, fileName);

    photoUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);

    List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();

    Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

    List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);

    for(ResolveInfo resolvedInfo : listCam) {
        String packageName = resolvedInfo.activityInfo.packageName;

        Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);

        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, resolvedInfo.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(packageName);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);

        cameraIntents.add(intent);
    }

    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();

    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);

    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select source");

    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[cameraIntents.size()]));

    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
}
```

The issue is when I take a photo with the camera it is not activating the onActivityResult which is below:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(requestCode));
    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(resultCode));

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO) {
            final boolean isCamera;

            if (data == null) {
                isCamera = true;
            } else {
                final String action = data.getAction();

                isCamera = MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE.equals(data.getAction());
            }

            Uri selectedImageUri;

            if (isCamera) {
                selectedImageUri = photoUri;
            } else {
                selectedImageUri = data == null ? null : data.getData();
            }

            photoText.setText(selectedImageUri.toString());

            Log.d(TAG, selectedImageUri.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

I have the below in my manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: did you tried to include `<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />` ?

Comment: Try not using `EXTRA_INTENTS`, and just calling `startActivityForResult()` on an `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`. BTW, the `Intent` delivered to `onActivityResult()` usually will not have an action string, and it certainly does not have to have the same action string as you used in your `Intent`.

Comment: There is no way to do it this way?

Comment: Apparently I cannot write to the file path (I am in Android Studio).